# http sniffer for windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, packet-sniffer

I am used to analyze http traffic response times and other useful statistical informations using justniffer for linux equipped servers.

Does anybody knows about an http sniffer like justniffer for Windows server?

Answer (score 3):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will run with the windows port of libpcap (installer includes it).

[Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a HTTP only proxy for good debugging, but more from a browser POV.

Wireshark is the nearest thing to justniffer, albeit with a GUI.  It can follow and reassemble TCP streams, and decode HTTP very clearly.

Comment: now days i prefer netmon to wireshark.

Comment: Eh. To each their own.  Wireshark is very reminiscent of it's tcpdump roots.

Comment: this tool is good.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21462

Comment: wireshark is good for debugging. But it does not collect info in a log format usable for statistics processing.
I need to collect http response times per url for graphing at a later stage.

fiddler is good for tracing and debugging your own web traffic. not entire web site traffic

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark has TShark.exe commandline tool (and not only that).

You can also use Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4. If you monitor http traffic, you should check the HTTP Troubleshoot Column Layout.

NM 3.4 also has nmcap.exe to monitor frames by commandline.

There is also RawCap, that allows you to capture frames from MS TCP Loopback inteface (127.0.0.1).

Comment: Microsoft Network Monitor seems to be very interesting but
none of them collect server response times per url. That is which i am mainly interested in.

I think that i will install a linux equiped virtual machine for "capturing" all network traffic of the guest window server.

Comment: did you look at the round trip analyzer from ms research